# Fix mouseover feature only show one value D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

Alright so I've been working on trying to get my stacked area chart to show the value on mouseover, and I got it to work (miracle) but it only shows one value, no matter where you move the mouse.  So when I go into any of the 5 different colors, it only shows one value for the whole color, no matter where the mouse is.  Could I get some help fixing this??

Here's my code:

```
   var t = 0;
   var n = 40;
   var dnsData = getDNS();
   var connectData = getConnect();
   var SSLData = getSSL();
   var sendData = getSend();
   var serverBusyData = getServerBusy();
   var receiveData = getReceive();


function getDNS() {
    var time = 0;
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<bardata.length; i++){
        var obj = {
            time: i,
            value: bardata[i].aggs.dns.avg
        };
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    t=time;
    return arr;
}

function getConnect() {
   var time = 0;
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < bardata.length; i++) {
       var obj = {
           time: i,
           value: bardata[i].aggs.con.avg + bardata[i].aggs.dns.avg
       };
       arr.push(obj);
   }
   t = time;
   return arr;
}

function getSSL() {
   var time = 0;
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < bardata.length; i++) {
       var obj = {
           time: i,
           value: bardata[i].aggs.ssl.avg + bardata[i].aggs.con.avg + bardata[i].aggs.dns.avg
       };
       arr.push(obj);
   }
   t = time;
   return arr;
}

function getSend() {
   var time = 0;
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < bardata.length; i++) {
       var obj = {
           time: i,
           value: bardata[i].aggs.snd.avg + bardata[i].aggs.ssl.avg + bardata[i].aggs.con.avg + bardata[i].aggs.dns.avg
       };
       arr.push(obj);
   }
   t = time;
   return arr;
}

function getServerBusy() {
   var time = 0;
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < bardata.length; i++) {
       var obj = {
           time: i,
           value: bardata[i].aggs.srvbsy.avg + bardata[i].aggs.snd.avg + bardata[i].aggs.ssl.avg + bardata[i].aggs.con.avg + bardata[i].aggs.dns.avg
       };
       arr.push(obj);
   }
   t = time;
   return arr;
}

function getReceive() {
   var time = 0;
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < bardata.length; i++) {
       var obj = {
           time: i,
           value: bardata[i].aggs.rcv.avg + bardata[i].aggs.srvbsy.avg + bardata[i].aggs.snd.avg + bardata[i].aggs.ssl.avg + bardata[i].aggs.con.avg + bardata[i].aggs.dns.avg
       };
       arr.push(obj);
   }
   t = time;
   return arr;
}

var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
},
   width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 425 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([t, n + 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 2500])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d, i) {
        return x(d.time);
     })
    .y0(function (d, i) {
        return y(d.value);
     })
    .y1(function(d, i){
        return height;
    });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 // extra svg to clip the graph and x axis as they transition in and out
var graph = g.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var axis = graph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(x.axis = xAxis);

/****************ADDED THESE TWO CHUNKS************************/
var focus = graph.append("svg")
    .style("display", "none");

focus.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "y")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("r", 4);
/****************ADDED THESE TWO CHUNKS************************/

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

var path5 = graph.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .data([receiveData])
    .attr("class", "receiveLine")
    .style({'fill':'#005266'})
    .append("title")
        .text(function(d, i){return d[i].value});

var path4 = graph.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .data([serverBusyData])
    .attr("class", "serverBusyLine")
    .style({'fill':'#008FB2'})
    .on("mouseover", function(){ focus.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

var path3 = graph.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .data([sendData])
    .attr("class", "sendLine")
    .style({'fill':'#00CCFF'})
    .on("mouseover", function(){ focus.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

var path2 = graph.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .data([SSLData])
    .attr("class", "SSLLine")
    .style({'fill':'#4DDBFF'})
    .on("mouseover", function(){ focus.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

var path1 = graph.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .data([connectData])
    .attr("class", "connectLine")
    .style({'fill':'#99EBFF'})
    .on("mouseover", function(){ focus.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

var path0 = graph.append("g")
    .append("path")
    .data([dnsData])
    .attr("class", "connectLine")
    .style({'fill':'#E6FAFF'})
    .on("mouseover", function(){ focus.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

   tick();

   function tick() {
      graph.select(".connectLine")
         .attr("d", line);

      graph.select(".SSLLine")
         .attr("d", line);

      graph.select(".sendLine")
         .attr("d", line);

      graph.select(".serverBusyLine")
         .attr("d", line);

      graph.select(".receiveLine")
         .attr("d", line);
   }

/****************ADDED THESE TWO CHUNKS************************/
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d){return d.value;}).left;

function mousemove(){
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(line, x0, 1),
        d0 = line[i - 1],
        d1 = line[i];
}
/****************ADDED THESE TWO CHUNKS************************/
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5kkv0ct4/
I appreciate any and all help!!

Comment: Your code doesn't have any `mouseover` handlers.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Well the way I'm doing it is just appending a "title" and then having it return the value, but I think it's just returning the first value on the whole area.  I need the value depending on where the mouse is.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Well yes, but to tell you where you're going wrong we really need to know what you're doing -- show us the code.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Oh.  I didn't realize I needed something like that and didn't just need to append the title that returns the value.  I'll see what I can do and let you know.  Thanks Lars.

Comment: Ok, I should have been clearer -- by appending a `title` element, you're giving an entire element the same tooltip, i.e. you can't do what you're looking for. I assumed that you were aware of that and now trying to change your code accordingly. You need something like in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569).

Comment: Okay @LarsKotthoff I updated my code in my question, and here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5kkv0ct4/1/  I know that the mouseover part is working because it was causing a bunch of errors, but I fixed the errors and now the value isn't showing up anywhere.

Comment: Well you're not setting the content for your tooltip. And you can't just copy and paste the code from the example, you have to adapt it to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick (but not so elegant) solution, you can listen for a mouse move on the `graph` SVG and then update the tool tips' text using the inverse (domain value) of the mouse coordinate in relation to the y-scale.

So, call the following code on your `graph` variable:

```
graph
    .on("mousemove", function() {
        d3.selectAll("path").select("title").text(y.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1]));
    });
```